# Confidence in cross validation

Tags: cross-validation

A paper I'm reading reports classification accuracy, calculated using 5-fold cross validation. Each accuracy number is reported together with 95% confidence given inside the parenthesis. For instance: 69.92 (0.545).

I understand accuracy is averaged over 5 tests data sets, but what is 95% confidence and how it is calculated?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I'd like to emphasize that it's really up to the paper should really to say what was calculated, and to spell out which approximations were used.

I'm afraid there's likely too much ambiguity to really find out without asking the authors.

---

I can think of two possibilities that you may be able to check out:

- This may be a binomial confidence interval. As only one number is given, possibly using the Gaussian approximation.
  The standard deviation of an observed fraction of cases $p$ (e.g. accuracy) is $$\sigma_\hat p = \sqrt{\frac{p (1 -p)}{n}}$$ p being the true fraction (or probability).

  Assuming that the 95 % c.i. used the normal approximation, so the reported $0.545 \% = 1.96 \sigma$, we can plug in the observed accuracy  $\hat p = 0.6992 \%$ for the true accuracy $p$ and solve for n:
  $$n = \frac{p (1 -p)}{(ci/2)^2} = \frac{0.6992 (1 - 0.6992)}{(0.00545/1.96)^2} \approx 27200$$

  (And at that sample size and $p$, the Normal approximation is safe to make. This calculation implicitly assumed the models are stable, so that variance due to model instability between the $k$ surrogate models is negligible.)

  If this lines up with the sample size in the paper, we probably found what they did.
- OTOH, if often see papers giving the standard deviation observed over the $k$ folds as observed uncertainty - this is a useful number, but of course in no way a 95 % confidence interval. And as it is not easy to calculate even the standard error of the mean here since we have possibly several relevant variance terms (the test sample size which I used above, model instability, and depending on the task at hand further sources of variance) at the very least the paper would need to explain what is included in this and what assumptions were taken.

Comment: yes, it would have to be based on the variance of a binomial proportion, $p$, which is indeed $\sqrt{pq/n}$

Comment: @NXGLogic: the important question is: is it? And, with that precision due to the large sample size and an accuracy of 70 %, I'd like to see something that model instability is negligible compared to those 0.5 % ci width.

Comment: The value in parentheses could be s.d. based on average over 5 folds.  I don't know why so many reports just don't pad the confusion matrix during any test fold they are in, and then just obtain one accuracy equal to $\sum_i c_{ii} / \sum_i \sum_j c_{ij}$? Probably because they didn't develop the code, and have no option but to determine the average and s.d.

Comment: @NXGLogic: neither do I know *why* this happens - but judging from the amount of questions around that topic I see here on CV.sx I know that there is a whole lot of confusion.